# How to edit row in a table with edit window

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem. It is about edit selected row in a table.
Each row  in the table has at the end botton to edit self.
If I click this button I can see edit window to edit selected data row from table.
 I am using  Bootstrap and have a problem. How to get  edit-window and after  click save on edit window  to replace selected row with new values??
It is best to look at my example!

### **This is my  [**DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/toshkaexe/te2wF/)**

Button to add new row

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  + Define a new visual feature
</button>
```

Table to add new row.

```
    <table class="table table-striped" id="table-visual-features">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Visual Feature</th>
                <th>Type [currently not used]</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is a value, which one has in selected row in a table. This value I would like to edit using edit window using Bootstrap

```
    console.log($(this).closest('tr').children('td').eq(0).text());
    console.log($(this).closest('tr').children('td').eq(1).text());
    console.log($(this).closest('tr').children('td').eq(2).text())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a reference to the row you are going to edit. What you could do for instance, is something like this:

```
var $table = $('#table-visual-features');
$table.on('click', 'tbody tr button[data-target=#edit]', function (event) {
    var $rows = $table.find('tbody tr');
    var $thisRow = $(this).parents('tr').eq(0);
    var index = $rows.index($thisRow);
    // open your modal here; now you know which row to edit
});
```

Comment: hi, I do not understand. Can you  do in jsfiddle Demo?